# Javascript Regex Tester for Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

did anybody know a good regex tester for javascript (i think there are differents between php regex and javascript? right?)

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: Have you seen [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com)? It's very visual and gives you real-time feedback for quickly understanding a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good (though not free) regex tester, debugger and converter is [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com). It's especially handy if you need to convert regular expressions from one flavor to another, and there is a grep tool built in.

[image: RegexBuddy screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

From my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312301/is-there-some-good-visual-regular-expression-editor/15912987#15912987):

I think you will find [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com) very valuable. Some advantages of debuggex are:

- Feedback is in real-time, so you can understand what's happening faster
- The ability to answer the question "Why does/doesn't it match here?" for **any position in your text**.
- **Very** heavy on the visuals, it was a core design decision behind it's creation

[image: picture of Debuggex]

At the time of writing, it only supports Javascript. However, more languages are planned for the future.

Comment: Excellent tool. Wish I could upvote more. A bit of a learning curve but the video helps a lot.

Comment: I wish I could paste text into debuggex, I would like to use it :/

Answer (score 2):

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)

It's actually for Ruby but it's pretty good for testing most standard regex. It allows lookbehind though which Javascript does not implement.

Comment: Apologies, it *doesn't* allow lookbehind!

Answer (score 2):

Try [Rejex](http://rejex.heroku.com/), it's a regexp tester for javascript

Answer (score 2):

For online testing try this realtime tester http://regextester.net/live-javascript-regex-tester.php

Answer (score 1):

There are differences, yes. There can even be slight differences in how regex is implemented between browsers (e.g. IE's "JScript" variant vs. Firefox), surprise surprise.

You should find plenty of JS-oriented regex testing tools on the web though. For example, I've used this one in the past, which is written in Javascript:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://webdevweapons.com/regextester/  It is simple and easy to use with the regex docs along side it for quick reference.