# Is there some good visual regular expression editor?

Tags: regex, editor

I have learned the basics about basic Regex, but I still feel I am far from being good.

As a beginner, it will be fantastic to have a WYSIWYG editor. So I was wondering if someone can give some recommendation on such editors? For various commonly-used versions of Regex, such as the basic one, the one for Python, for Perl, for bash, ....

Or if you have other nice ways/tools (not necessarily in the form of editor) to recommend for helping master different versions of Regex, that will be nice as well!

Thanks and regards!

---

MY OSes are Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7.

Comment: I answered something like this [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/108141/30042).

Comment: there is a good one http://visual-regexp.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Here is "reverse" tool - to generate regexp from given string and grups from user:
http://txt2re.com/index.php3

Comment: http://www.regexr.com

Answer (score 8):

What is "good" depends on what is most useful to **you**. For me, though, these are the key features for a good regex editor (besides the ability to test and create regular expressions, of course, which is a prerequisite to be called a "regex editor"  :-) :

1. Displays matches hierarchically with captured groups.
2. Explains/analyzes an entered regex in plain English, showing a hierarchical tree.
3. Translates your regex into code for a language of your choice.

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), as @Max mentioned, does all these but there is also a *free* alternative, [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) that also does them very well. These two utilities are the **only** ones I have found with the crucial ability to explain a regex. Here is an example from RegexBuddy:

---

[image: regex explained in English]

Comment: Expresso++ great tool!

Answer (score 7):

This is a nice online regex editor/tester: http://myregexp.com/

Comment: "This Domain Name Has Expired"

Answer (score 5):

I think you will find [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com) very valuable. Some advantages of debuggex are:

- Feedback is in real-time, so you can understand what's happening faster
- The ability to answer the question "Why does/doesn't it match here?" for **any position in your text**.
- **Very** heavy on the visuals, it was a core design decision behind it's creation

[image]

At the time of writing, it only supports Javascript. However, more languages are planned for the future.

Answer (score 3):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Regexper - An Online Tool For Beautiful JavaScript Regexp Visualizations](http://www.regexper.com/) - which recently came out.

Regexper is a tool for visualizing JavaScript regular expressions online.  The tool can be used as a teaching tool or simply as a tool to follow the logic of your JavaScript regex to get a better understanding of it.  It might especially be useful when you have to write complex regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [PCREck](https://github.com/amireh/PCREck), a multi-dialect regular expression editor, it is also open source if you care about that.

Comment: one more visulal regexp constructor http://visual-regexp.rhcloud.com